# SQLite how to store decimal 0.00 and 1.10 instead of 0 and 1.1?

Tags: sqlite

This is my SQLite query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts` (id INTEGER NOT NULL, price DECIMAL(10,2) default 0.00);", conn);
```

I want to avoid saving 0 instead of 0.00 or 1.1 instead of 1.10. Is it possible in SQLite?

Comment: I think storing like that could be possible for a text type value, but has no sense for a numeric one. Do you mean displaying to format like this?

Answer (score 1):

You have a decimal datatype that can store up to two decimal digits.

When you insert data, you can ignore non-significant digits. The following commands are equivalent:

```
insert into accounts (id, price) values (1, 1.1);
insert into accounts (id, price) values (1, 1.10);
```

SQLite stores it in an internal format that you don’t need to worry about. The value can be formatted as needed when it is read in a `select` query.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I am presenting that data with datagridview (and for example, I need sum of 1000 to be presented as 1000.00) and user can edit that numbers .... So I want to avoid writing additional code just to present data with .00 or .10 ... if sqlite offers it. Same code in MySql works fine and always stores 2 decimal digits even if they are 0s. BTW, I have a lot of calculations and sorting in my code so storing this data into String isn't an option

Answer (score 1):

There is no `DECIMAL` data type in SQLite as you can find here: [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html).
By defining the column `price` as `DECIMAL(10,2)` you just define its affinity as `NUMERIC`, but this does not mean that the numeric values that you will store will have precision of 2 decimal places.
You can store anything in that column, even strings.

What you can do is format the numbers when you query the table with the function `printf()`:

```
SELECT id, printf("%.2f", price) AS price FROM accounts
```

Or redefine the column as `TEXT`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts` (id INTEGER NOT NULL, price TEXT DEFAULT '0.00');
```

and store the values like:

```
INSERT INTO accounts(id, price) VALUES 
  (1, printf("%.2f", 1.1)),
  (2, printf("%.2f", 1000));
```

But when you want to aggregate or do any kind of numeric calculations like:

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM accounts
```

or

```
SELECT 1.1 * price FROM accounts
```

you will still need to use `printf()` to format the results:

```
SELECT printf("%.2f", SUM(price)) FROM accounts
```

or

```
SELECT printf("%.2f", 1.1 * price) FROM accounts
```